# assembly subroutines get called twice without even being called from main

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, x86-64, subroutine

I'm trying to define some subroutines that have calls to printf in them.
A very trivial example is as follows:

```
extern printf
LINUX        equ     80H
EXIT         equ     60

section .data
    intfmt: db "%ld", 10, 0

segment .text
    global  main

main:
    call os_return      ; return to operating system

os_return:
    mov  rax, EXIT      ; Linux system call 60 i.e. exit ()
    mov  rdi, 0     ; Error code 0 i.e. no errors
    int  LINUX      ; Interrupt Linux kernel

test:
    push rdi
    push rsi
    mov rsi, 10
    mov rdi, intfmt
    xor rax, rax
    call printf
    pop rdi
    pop rsi
    ret
```

Here test just has a call to printf that outputs the number 10 to the screen. I would not expect this to get called as I have no call to it.

However when compiling and running:

```
nasm -f elf64 test.asm
gcc -m64 -o test test.o
```

I get the output:

```
10
10
```

I'm totally baffled and wondered if someone could explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int 80H` invokes the 32-bit system call interface, which a) uses the 32-bit system call numbers and b) is intended for use by 32-bit code, not 64-bit code.  Your code is actually performing a `umask` system call with random parameters.

For a 64-bit system call, use the `syscall` instruction instead:

```
...
os_return:
    mov  rax, EXIT      ; Linux system call 60 i.e. exit ()
    mov  rdi, 0     ; Error code 0 i.e. no errors
    syscall         ; Interrupt Linux kernel
...
```

Comment: Thanks! Do I put the value 60 (EXIT) into rdi then instead of rax, similar to calling printf?

Comment: No, putting the syscall number in `rax` and the first argument in `rdi` is correct.  See http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf (appendix A in particular) for some documentation of the kernel syscall ABI and the differences from the user-level calling conventions.

Comment: Sorry to keep badgering you about this but I changed the line "int LINUX" to call syscall and added extern syscall to the top and still get the two ten's. Is there any chance you could show me a mini example of how to call syscall? Thanks so much :)

Comment: See edited answer: I'm talking about the `syscall` x86-64 instruction (which is the closest 64-bit equivalent to doing things with `int 80h`), not the `syscall()` library function.

Comment: That was why I was getting confused. It works - thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

I would say that your call to `exit` is failing, so when it returns, it falls through to the `test` function, that prints the first 10.

Then when you return with `ret` you go back to the instruction just after the `call os_return`, that is, well `os_return`. The call to exit fails again and falls through to the `test` function again. But this time the `ret` returns from the `main` function and the program ends.

About why is the `exit` call failing, I cannot tell as I don't have a 64-bit system available. But you could disassemble the `exit` function from libc and see how it is done there. My guess is that the `int LINUX` interface is 32-bit only, as it exists only for historic compatibility, and 64-bit linux in not so old.

Comment: `int 0x80` is the 32 system call interface, in which syscall 60 is `umask`. See [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087730/what-happens-if-you-use-the-32-bit-int-0x80-linux-abi-in-64-bit-code)